# How are the number of strings in a pulley system quantified?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

Scrolling down to the **Pulley** section of [this](http://www2.phy.ilstu.edu/pte/489.01content/simple_machines/simple_machines.html) website, it states that

> The ideal mechanical advantage (IMA) of a pulley is directly dependent upon the number of support strings, N.

This is the image it provides:

[image: Three pulley systems diagramed with the number of strings]

I don't understand how the number of strings is determined if it's really just one string. The horizontal dotted line seems to have something to do with this, but the extension of the strings in the diagram seems to be contrived after already knowing the number of strings, especially after comparing the first and second pulley systems.

How is the number of strings in a pulley system determined? If determining the number of strings in a pulley is simply not suitable for finding the IMA of a pulley, what other way without knowing the input and output forces is there?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "mechanical advantage" is all about reducing the force (effort) you need to apply to perform the same amount of work (lift a weight a specific height). Work is force times distance. You can do the same amount of work by reducing the force (the effort you need to apply) and increasing the distance you need to apply that force. Mechanical advantage makes it possible to lift a weight that would not be otherwise possible because of the limit of the amount of force you are capable of applying.

With the exception of the first diagram you show, all of the other pulley systems allow you to use less effort (force) to do the same amount of work in lifting the weight. They do that by increasing the distance the rope has to be pulled so that you can apply less force.

The first diagram simply reverses the direction of the applied force. Why would you do that? It's because it would be easier to pull down to raise the weight than to pull up on the weight, because when you pull down you can use your own weight as part of the force pulling down. But you still have to apply the same force, so there is technically no mechanical advantage.

> How is the number of strings in a pulley system determined?

Basically, it is based on how much the complete string has to move to result in movement of the weight.

Although overall you have only one string, by routing the string around the pulleys you effectively increase the distance the overall string has to move in order to lift the weight.

In the second diagram, for each unit length the upward force is applied to the right, the weight moves one half a unit length upward. So you apply half the force to lift the weight using the pulley than without the pulley, but you apply it for twice the distance to get the same work (conservation of energy) because there are two string segments.

In the third diagram, for each unit length the downward force to the right is applied, the weight raises one fourth a unit length upward. The work is the same, but the applied force (effort) is one fourth that of lifting the weight without the pulley system.

Hope this helps.